# Trying to save images to directory, Saving into an unknown place

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a facial/emotion detection application for my dissertation and have hit the wall that has stopped me from progressing and I cant figure out the reason why it is preventing the image saving to the directory of the phone. It seems to be saving to the SD card, but I dont use an SDcard in my phone / an emulated DCIM.

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)+ "/" + UUID.randomUUID(), toString()+ ".jpg");
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                    image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes() [0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        {
                            if (image != null)
                                image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This is the code I have to create the file and save to the location, I have tried other solutions but they throw out errors.

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CustomFolder");
            File file;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                boolean success = folder.mkdir();
                if (success){
                    file = new File(folder.getPath() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID(), toString()+ ".jpg");
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(FacialDetection.this, "Failed to save file to folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                file = new File(folder.getPath() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID(), toString()+ ".jpg");
            }

            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                    image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes() [0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        {
                            if (image != null)
                                image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {

                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try {
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(***file***);
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                    }finally {
                        if (outputStream != null)
                            outputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            };

            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(FacialDetection.this, "Saved " + ***file***, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createCameraPreview();
                }
            };
```

The updated code, stuff bold and italic is what is throwing errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will advise you to create your own custom folder location this way:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CustomFolder");
        File file;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            boolean success = folder.mkdir();
            if (success){
                file = new File(folder.getPath() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID(), toString()+ ".jpg");
            }else {
                //Some message
            }
        }else {
            file = new File(folder.getPath() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID(), toString()+ ".jpg");
        }
//The rest of your code...
```

Comment: I have updated the code and i am getting errors. I believe i have added it in wrong

Comment: the two 'file' variables with *** *** around them are highlighted red.. and it wants me to change it to finalfile which makes all other file variables wanting to be deleted

Comment: Yes, you need to make it final because you are accessing it from within an inner class. And change the Toast to `...file.getPath().toString()`

Comment: sorry, im struggling to understand what the line of code would be for the Toast change? what would it look like as i removed the toast and added that, it is now highlighted all yellow

Comment: Something like this `Toast.makeText(FacialDetection.this, "Saved " +file.getPath().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: assert false;
                    Toast.makeText(FacialDetection.this, "Saved " + file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
                }

Comment: that is what i come out with, without any errors in the code

Comment: It is still saving to /storage/emulated/0/CustomFolder ... is this SD or internal directory

Comment: That's the device storage, internal storage if you like :)

Comment: Ah okay, now i have it working...  i have a new problem, it is saving to the desired folder but every photo i take it saves as the same name and just rewrites the image over again

Comment: It's because the file variable is final so the randomUUID is not having effect on it. You can fix this by converting `final file` into a one element array
`final File[] file` then `file[0] = new File(folder.getPath() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID(), toString()+ ".jpg");`. Access `file[0]` whenever you want to use it

Answer (score 0):

You're calling:
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)

I would speculate that .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() means get directory on SD card. Is there a getInternal... method?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create folder !exist
String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/myFoldername";
File folder = new File(folderPath);
if (!folder.exists()) {
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(folderPath);
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
}
//create a new file
newFile = new File(folderPath, newPhoto.getName());

if (newFile != null) {
    // save image here
    Uri relativePath = Uri.fromFile(newFile);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, relativePath);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: How would i implement this with the current code i have?